# discrepancy between data used and

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

In AWS RDS our DB is using up a total of 75 mb out of 5 gb,

```
mysql> SELECT sum((data_length+index_length)/power(1024,2)) tablesize_mb FROM information_schema.tables order by tablesize_mb desc;
+-------------------+
| tablesize_mb      |
+-------------------+
| 72.25519466400146 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

There are 26 logs all at a few kb in the instance section

Yet I have < 500 mb Freeable Space

What could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: When you say <500mb freeable space, what is it out of? Also Syntax tip: If you add 4 spaces before a block of text, you can make it into a code block.

Comment: it's out of 5 gb

Comment: I'm sorry (and no expert on RDS) but I still don't get it.  Could you cut-and-paste into your question some output showing the problem?  Where is this 5GB limit set?  How do you know you only have 500MB of it left?  At the moment, I'm not sure this question is answerable - though it might just be my ignorance about RDS that makes it appear so.